# Is there an std or boost container that avoids race condition between its insert and find methods?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, containers

Each thread may insert an object to the container (at most once) using 'insert' function.
Hereafter, the thread may try to access this object using 'get' function.
Therefore, there is no race between 'insert' and 'get' when used by the same thread.
However, a different thread may try to insert its own object while another thread has called 'get'

I need a container where this situation does not need any synchronization method.

The number of threads may vary dramatically between executions.

```
class Object;
class Container<Object>;

Container<Object> g_container;

void insert(int threadId)
{
    ScopedLock<Mutex> lock(insertMutex);
    Object obj;
    g_container[threadId] = obj;
}

Object get(int threadId)
{
    return g_container[threadId];
}
```

Comment: Under such conditions, you usually handle this by giving each thread their own container.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that once in a while I need to iterate over all the objects and collect information from them. Therefore, they need to be contained together.

Comment: How do you plan to iterate over container when threads are still inserting?

Comment: Since this is a rare operation I don't mind locking - using the insertMutex.

Comment: Two notes: you need to lock for reading too; the STL does not provide any intrinsic locking mechanism.

Comment: If you are under windows you can take a look at [Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx#queue) for thread safe containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vector of container pointers. Each thread manages their own container instance, and registers it with the array of container pointers.

```
template <typename T>
struct Container {
    Mutex insertMutex;
    ContainerType<T> container;
    int index;
    void insert (T &obj) {
        ScopedLock<Mutex> lock(insertMutex);
        container.insert(obj);
    }
    T get () {
        return *container.begin();
    }
    void register_container () {
        if (index != 0) return;
        if (counter == MAX_THREADS) throw 0;
        index = ++counter;
        ScopedLock<Mutex> lock(registerMutex);
        containers.push_back(this);
    }
    static std::vector<Container *> containers;
    static Atomic<int> counter;
    static Mutex registerMutex;
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<Container<T> *> Container<T>::containers;

template <typename T>
Atomic<int> Container<T>::counter;

template <typename T>
Mutex Container<T>::registerMutex;
```

Now, you can iterate over the `Container<T>::containers` to access all containers.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is usually called a "lock-free data structure".

I understand why you think you need a lock-free container, but I can almost promise you that you don't. They are usually more trouble than they're worth. You should just have one mutex which governs all access to an ordinary container. Lock the mutex to insert in the container. Lock the mutex to remove from the container. And lock the mutex before reading (or iterating over) the container.

Here is some helpful discussion from Herb Sutter, chair of the C++ standards committee:

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lock-free-code-a-false-sense-of-security/210600279

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes, just so. If at any time it's possible that another thread may modify the container while you're reading it, then all reads and writes must be synchronized with a mutex. As you say, locking an uncontested mutex is actually pretty cheap (usually just an atomic read).

Answer (score 1):

+1 to James Brock.

But it sounds more like you want one container for each thread, yet mutexed, and locking/unlocking the mutexes is cheap because 99.9% of the time the operation succeeds the first time. But the "master" thread does have the ability to occasionally pause the other threads while examining them.

If each thread has only one object, the containers go away. Just lock the objects. Don't worry about the cost of locking unless it's a proven performance problem. In that case, the problem isn't to remove the locks, but merely to reduce their usage frequency. So keep the objects locked and only do an unlock every hundredth time or so. Combine with a condition variable if necessary.

Comment: +1 Right, and if you change the container from `class Container<Object>` to `class Container<Object*>`, then each thread can access the object it owns by simply keeping a local pointer to that object, bypassing the need to read the container.